# High-resolution texture mods for the Steam version

Tags: steam, mods, deus-ex

I'm looking to begin playing through Deus-Ex which I purchased on Steam.  I've heard about high-resolution texture packs for the original game.

I've come across [forum post](http://www.offtopicproductions.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1206) which explains how to use this with Steam.  Is this still the best way to achieve using these textures?

I hope not, because I don't have a retail copy of the game.

Comment: @user598527 Your edits are starting to turn this into a mod request question. What was here was fine, it didn't need editing.

Comment: @Frank: I've now noticed this as well. The question is unclear, I don't completely understand what he is asking. Adding [mods] tag was needed, though.

Comment: @Frank: I don't use texture mods with Deus Ex, if you're wondering.

Comment: What are you asking? Do you want to know which version is the best for (texture) mods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the ultimate Deus Ex experience, follow these [steps](http://kentie.net/article/dxguide/index.htm). It works with the Steam version.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be to try a mod Deus Ex Revision. I played both versions, original and Revision, and certainly it's worth a try. Story stays the same but Revision introduces a lot of cosmetic changes which aims to make user experience closer to modern titles.

Revision includes some existing modification but team also added their own work. General changes includes, as below.

- Improved textures.
- Improved models - player, NPC, robots, weapons, etc.
- Improved environment - more detailed maps, some level changed completely.
- Improved soundtrack.

Homepage: https://www.dx-revision.com/ (also available on Steam)

There are some comparison videos available. Here's one of them:

Comment: "Revision introduces a lot of cosmetic changes which make user experience much, much better" - please elaborate.

Comment: Hi-res textures, new models - more detailed, new maps - bigger and more complex, environment more rich - you have some more stuff lying around, can't interact with it but overall experience is better. In general, world does feel more lively and realistic. There is not a big impact for story line so what is good stays good, and what is bad (in terms of modern visuals) has been improved. That is more than enough for me to play it again, and have fun from exploring new places. And why have you down voted BTW? Is my answer not in line with any rules?

Comment: Your opinion reads like a fact, you should also add additional detail.

Comment: Fair enough. Answer improved.